# SQS triggering lambda in Serverless has latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-serverless

I have a use case below

1. StepFunction -> Lambda -> EventBridge to SQS triggering lambda

When the message receives to Eventbridge it will then publish to SQS and SQS will trigger the lambda. What I have noticed here is every time some message is pushed it takes almost 21 Sec to reach the final lambda.

**Configuration of SQS:**

- Visibility Timeout: 30 sec
- Dead letter Queue: Enabled
- Delay Delivery: 0
- receiveMessageDelay: Tried both Short and long poll

Lambda is inside VPC

When I did my analysis, all the bridges is happening in instant but SQS triggering Lambda takes 21 Sec.

All the Blogs am referring to say, it will happen in instant but for me no luck.

Am not sure if my configuration is wrong. Any help is more valuable to me.

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: From 21 sec, I might think you've set long polling (max 20 sec). How about set `Receive message wait time` 1 sec?

Comment: @shimo, Yes I did both short polling and long polling (0 and 1 and 20). But for all am getting the same latency. But, sometimes it works very quickly irrelevant of the short or long poll.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for your workflow? Can you remove some of the elements, such as the SQS queue?

Comment: Yes we prefer to use SQS for the letter retention period (max 4 days) and the easy setup for dead letter queues

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Guna's own answer, we had the same problem, and found that the reason was a documented SQS limitation because we had a `batchSize` configured of 100 and a `maximumBatchingWindow` of 1.

AWS states:

> If you're using a batch window and your SQS queue contains very low traffic, Lambda might wait for up to 20 seconds before invoking your function. This is true even if you set a batch window lower than 20 seconds.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Once we removed both the `batchSize` and `maximumBatchingWindow` configuration settings, the SQS-Lambda invocation latency dramatically decreased.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, have noticed that SQS trigger lambda settings in serverless configured for maximumBatchingWindow to specify the maximum amount of time in seconds to gather records before invoking the function. Which is not required when batch size is 1.